# How to model very large work queues in Akka?

Tags: scala, concurrency, queue, akka, bigdata

I am writing a scala script to download all items from the hacker news API. There are ~12M items, each being a JSON of ~200 bytes.

I identified the following issues:

- Storing the data: I tried to save each item as a single JSON file, but it became very hard just to barely list them (using Linux, ext4 file system). So I changed it to just append JSON items to multiple (100) files (by taking the item's id module 100).
- Keeping track of what has been downloaded, because I want to be able to stop/continue the application. First I tried writing the downloaded ids to a textfile, but it turned out a little bit buggy. So now I just read all the items and collect the ids. (It works.)

All this is done with 1 Master actor and an arbitrary number of Worker actors (tens). The Master has a Queue[Int] and pops it and Workers ask for work.

The problem I am having is fairly simple but I haven't been able to solve it in a nice way.

I can collect the ids from items already downloaded in a list. But what I really need is the complement to that set; I need all the items I have not downloaded, up to the highest item id.

I tried using a range (1 to maxItemId) and subtracting the set of done jobs but it is really slow. reaaaaaaally slow.

Now I am using a Stream, and when a worker asks for a job, I check if the stream's (the next job) has already been done. If so, I give it to the Worker. Otherwise I check the next one.

The problem with this approach is that I can not put jobs back at the stream if they fail. That would be easy with the Queue; but then again I am having trouble just setting up the queue with millions of items.

What could be a better approach to this? I don't think the issues here are trivial, this is a very large number of tasks to perform and keep track of, but it shouldn't be so hard as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, I think you don't need a very complicated data structure here.

Assuming your ids are sequential from 1 to `maxItemId`, you can use an array of `Boolean` with `maxItemId` size to keep track of processed items. You initialize this array by reading the processed ids. And you find the next job by searching for the next `false` entry.

Assuming that your `maxItemId` is around 12M, iterating over all items is pretty much instantaneous.

Comment: This is ok. But how to serialize and desseralize properly?

Comment: Do you mean the JSON document? I understood that your solution was working for you. Anyway, maybe it is easier to consider a database instead of creating your own persistence solution. Try something like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/community), which is totally based on persisting / retrieving JSON documents and can easily handle 12M items.